# Add link into a info text

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have search box with Ajax like this;

And I want to change NotfindText like this: "No results but you can try advanced search from [here](http://google.com) "

But I can't add link. And I have no knowledge about Ajax. Can anybody help me?

```
function searchxx(a){(function(d){var f={blogURL:"",srcBlank:"http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-htG7vy9vIAA/Tp0KrMUdoWI/AAAAAAAABAU/e7XkFtErqsU/s1600/grey.gif",findText:"Search results for keyword",NotfindText:"No result!",Showthumb:true,LoadingText:"Searching...",scrthumbSize:50,summaryLength:100};f=d.extend({},f,a);var b=d("#ajax-search-form"),e=b.find(":text");b.append('<div id="search-result"></div>');var c=d("#search-result");b.on("submit",function(){var g=e.val();c.show().html('<div class="load">'+f.LoadingText+"</div>");d.get((f.blogURL===""?window.location.protocol+"//"+window.location.host:f.blogURL)+"/feeds/posts/default?alt=json-in-script&q="+g+"&max-results=9999",function(w){var v=w.feed.entry,r,q,u,s,h,k,m="";if(v!==undefined){m="<h4>"+f.findText+" &quot;"+g+"&quot;</h4>";m+='<a class="close" href="/">&times;</a><ol>';for(var o=0;o<v.length;o++){var l=new RegExp(g,"ig"),u=v[o].title.$t.replace(l,"<mark>"+g+"</mark>");for(var n=0,t=v[o].link.length;n<t;n++){if(v[o].link[n].rel=="alternate"){s=v[o].link[n].href}}r=("content" in v[o])?v[o].content.$t:("summary" in v[o])?v[o].summary.$t:"";if(f.Showthumb===true){var p=/<script\b[^<]*(?:(?!<\/script>)<[^<]*)*<\/script>/gi;h=d("<div></div>").append(r.replace(p,""));k=h.find("img");if("media$thumbnail" in v[o]){q=v[o].media$thumbnail.url.replace(/\/s[0-9]+\-c/g,"/s"+f.scrthumbSize+"-c")}else{if(k.length!=0){q=k[0].src}else{q=f.srcBlank}}}r=r.replace(/<\S[^>]*>/g,"");if(r.length>f.summaryLength){r=r.substring(0,f.summaryLength)+"..."}r=r.replace(l,"<mark>"+g+"</mark>");m+='<li><a href="'+s+'" >'+(f.Showthumb===true?'<img width="'+f.scrthumbSize+'" height="'+f.scrthumbSize+'" src="'+q+'"/>':"")+"<strong>"+u+"</strong></a>"+(f.summaryLength>0?"<p>"+r+"</p>":"")+"</li>"}m+="</ol>";c.html(m)}else{c.html('<a class="close" href="/">&times;</a><strong>'+f.NotfindText+"</strong>")}},"jsonp");return false});b.on("click",".close",function(){c.fadeOut();return false})})(jQuery)};
```

**Here is SS:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem like an AJAX question, you just need to give a string to the Notfindtext key. Replace Notfindtext with this line:

```
NotfindText: "No results but you can try advanced search 
from <a href=\"http://google.com/\">HERE</a>",
```

Does this help? Check your Chrome javascript console and see what errors are being thrown.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply but booth solution doesn't work.
I edited first post and added all codes. 
Also my test site is: http://esnekt.blogspot.com/

Comment: Sory It works now

I just erease semicolon and it works :) This one:
("No result, but you can do a search <a href='~/link'>here</a>");

Thank you guys :)

Answer (score 0):

One thing, all the responce that will be written here is a responce caught from the page where Ajax runs. So you would be writing all the codes there instead of here.

You have not provided any of your code, that is a -1 for your question. But I won't, only thinking that you might add the code here in the question.

Ok, how to add the `<a>` link here is the example:

```
Response.Write("No result, but you can do a search <a href='~/link'>here</a>");
```

This way, that was the respone. Else you can use this:

```
success: function (data) {
  if(data == "") {
   NotfindText = "No result, but you can do a search <a href='~/link'>here</a>";
  }
}
```

But again, this is not what ajax would write. You are just writing the code on your own. Its of no use.

You must use `success` to make sure this is written once the ajax provides no result.